# How to extend storage in Swift(OpenStack) service?

Tags: amazon-s3, openstack, openstack-swift

I installed a SAIO(swift all in one) in my server, it's a ubuntu 14.04 system.

I create a loopback device for storage by following commands:

`sudo mkdir /srv
sudo truncate -s 20GB /srv/swift-disk
sudo mkfs.xfs /srv/swift-disk`

(http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html)

Now, I don't have enough disk to storage, I want to extand swift storage, what can I do for it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have disk space to create another virtual disk?

If so you can create another virtual disk (follow the steps in the link you provided. It's the same steps you took to create the first virtual disk) and add the new virtual disk to the ring, using the "swift-ring-build" command.